# GPU at 80-100% all the time playing Perfect Golf (Unity 5.2.3)

Tags: nvidia-geforce, display-driver

I'm playing Perfect Golf. https://store.steampowered.com/app/288140/Perfect_Golf/ 6 year old golfing simulator that uses Unity 5.2.3. But as soon as I start the game the GPU goes mental and goes from 80-100% all the time even though you're at main menu.

I have a MSI Geforce 1070 TI so its way more than enough to run the game smoothly.

I have removed the drivers in Safe Mode (no networking) using this utility:

https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html

And reinstalled latest drivers but no difference..... GPU is running mental......

I have tried to toggle vsync on and off in the game but it doesn't matter at all :(

I made this video that shows what happens when starting the game.

https://1drv.ms/v/s!AoKUUShuzI9HkLVEph08J8t3GZcLoQ

Is this a known issue for Unity 5 games?

EDIT: GPU goes straight to 90% when loading the low resolution video that is the intro

Comment: This would be better asked of the game developers. There are far too many variables to tackle this type of topic on a general computing site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in the game's software, or less likely with the GPU's driver.  Either way, the correct course of action would be to report the bug to the game's developers.  Whether or not they will look into and fix a bug in a 6 year old game is a different story.

Comment: Ye. Sadly the game company Perfect Parallel doesn't exist any more. But thanks anyways :)